# Help with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that, given an ingredient line, will tell me the quantity of that ingredient. Here are some sample values:

- 8 ounces semisweet chocolate
- 6 eggs
- 3/4 cup sugar
- 1-tablespoon espresso powder
- 1/2 cup Dutch processed baking cocoa
- 1/4 cup unsweetened cocoa
- 1/2 cup confectioners' sugar
- 2 cups heavy cream
- 2 to 4 dried scallops (optional)
- 1 1/2 cups carrots
- Raspberry and apricot preserves

Whenever a quantity exists (all the examples except for the last) it needs to get the quantity. So, for the first example "8 ounces of semisweet chocolate" it needs to return "8 ounces".

How do I do this using PHP regex?

Comment: So you would be maintaining a list of possible quantity units somewhere, correct? What language / regex flavour do you need this for? If you ask me, this would be easier to do using a normal programming / scripting language, walking through each ingredient, splitting it, and comparing the first and second members against a list of known units. This is not really regular expression territory

Comment: How should the expression deal with "3/4 cup **of** sugar"?

Comment: Yes, I will have a list of possible units. I am using PHP. 'of' should be removed. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I meant it 'of' should be ignored.

Comment: That's going to be a *really* tricky one. Matching all the combinations in the example is relatively straightforward, but getting a regex that will match every possible combination in a natural-language recipe will be next to impossible.

Comment: No need for that. It just needs to parse an ingredient line, not a recipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your examples (and a few others I can think of),

```
^[ \d/.-]*(?:to\s+[ \d/.-]*)?(?:ounces?|cups?|(?:table|tea)spoons?)?
```

would work.

If you want to avoid to capture a trailing space (as this regex would do after a number not followed by a unit), add `(?=\s)` to the end of the regex.

Comment: would this miss the 6 on eggs though?